# link between java and javascript

Tags: java, javascript, web

I want to send raw data from server which is written in simple java program to javascript. The server is not the java applet ( i don't want to involve java applet). I want to have access to those data from javascript or HTML5 to display in web browser. 
LiveConnect, JavaFX,etc deal with java applet. I also don't  prefer servlet. This is because i have simple java server program ( not applet or servlets)
Could anyone please how can i play with those raw data in java server from client side ( javascript) to display in web browser( web application).

Comment: Have you heard about AJAX and JQuery?

Comment: i have simple java server program( not applet or servlets). Can you tell us which one u r using apart from servlets.

Comment: @ Joraid, suppose I have x,y,z,a,b,c data in my server (java), I want x,y,z,a,b,c to be present in userinterface way using web application for web browser user.
I have also seen in AJAX but my confusion part is how does it know that x,y,z....is located in my server using request. Because these data are real time generated chat data.
could u plz elaborate with example...
 I m really stuck in this place..
thanks in advance

Comment: @ Ganesh , Thanks for Reply . Following is my structure I used in my java server ( chat application)
       
                  import something.....;
                     import something1....;
 
                         public class demo {
  
                       public static void main(String[] args){
          ......
          ...
           }
           }
    Suppose if one client send data ("hello World") to another client. They only see normally ,not using User Interface. But I want to show "hello World" in very simple web application ( could be by alerting in javascript)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a web container (tomcat, glassfish, jboss, etc) as the bridge of client browser and java application in your server to access your java application and its classes. Then, the client browser send request to the web container. Web container send request to your java application and send respond from the java application to client browser.

Comment: I will surely look for web container stuff. If you can explain it with an example showing how to access java class from javascript , it will be really great for me...and really helpful as well